# Have an Index against a varchar(6000), or a md5 sum (for comparison with the whole value, not just part of it)?

Tags: mysql, innodb

Using MySQL, I have to compare new values to rows on a column `code` that is varchar(6000).

```
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - --
| id (int(11))| code     (varchar(6000))                 | 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - --
| 1           | alpha : function bar(1)                  |
| 2           | dog.hasFourLegs()                        |
 ...
```

I check if a new input `code` is equal to the one in the database, 'frequently' (once every 10 minutes).
I can obviously have a new column with a md5 sum of the `code`, and compare md5 sums, and index this `md5_code` . But isn't indexing the `code` varchar(6000) more efficient ? (efficient in time, and in storage space).
The table will have about 300 000 rows in the long term. Innodb used.

Extra question : is there a big difference of behaviour between innodb and mysam for this problem ?

Comment: If you can allow for duplicate rows to exist in the database (e.g. for later mergers), i'd suggest to put an extra 64-bit integer column in the table and store one part of the md5 value there. The index on that column will be very efficient.

Comment: I know that it would be very efficient. But I wonder if innodb or mysam handle that by itself. Btw, I haven't thought about taking just part of the hash, that's an idea.

Comment: The problem in using MyISAM is its table locking feature, this engine is good if data don't get update so frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the actual data you have, Prefix Indexes may be the solution for you.

MySQL lets you set up an index that only looks at the first N characters of the field.  For example, to index the first 20 characters only:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD KEY(code(20));
```

How many characters to index depends on your data.  For example, if the strings in all your records start with the same 3 letters then having a prefix index of 3 won't help you at all.  You need to scan your data to determine the right index length for that data set.

There are some tips for choosing the prefix length in this [Percona Best Practices presentation](http://www.percona.com/files/presentations/WEBINAR-MySQL-Indexing-Best-Practices.pdf) (search for Choosing Prefix Length).